# Apple Automator Question Copy and Paste

Tags: ms-office, automator, copy-paste

How would I copy all of the text from a powerpoint presentation and paste it into a word document?

Comment: If I remember correct pptx files are sort of archives. Maybe you can unpack it and there is a text file containing all the text. Not sure though.

Comment: It's a zip full of XML files

Comment: I can imagine a way in which only the body text is extracted from the XML's but it involves some coding and I would have no clue how to do that in Automator.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Try the following workflow:

1. Ask for Finder Items
2. Convert Format of Powerpoint Presentations
      New Format: Outline (Rich Text Format)
3. Move Finder Items
      To: Desktop (or as you wish)

This should work.

I tested it. Then right click on the RTF and open with MS Word.

Here it is for you to download [Powerpoint to RTF workflow.](http://cl.ly/2T1H0c2H0h1F)